# how do you convert string into uppercase c++

Tags: c++

I am not allowed to use toupper()

these are my functions, one function has to pass the string by reference.

```
void Uppercase(string x)
{
int y = 0;
while (y < x.length)
{
    x[y] = x[y] - 32;
    y++;
}
}

void uppercase(string &x)
{
int y = 0;
while (y < x.length)
{
    x[y] = x[y] - 32;
    y++;
}
```

Do I at least have the right idea?

I get this error when I build it....

Error   5   error C2446: '<' : no conversion from 'unsigned int (__thiscall std::basic_string,std::allocator>::* )(void) throw() const' to 'int'  c:\users\edwingomez\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\homework\homework\homework6.cpp   18  1   Homework

Comment: 32 is a magic number and should be replaced with a constant at the very least.

Comment: You need to check that the character is in the correct range 'a'-'z', and the first function don't do anythings, the string is modified inside, but the result is not see.

Comment: You left out the parentheses: `x.length()`.

Comment: wowwww I completely missed that lol. sorry now it works :D thank you guys

Answer (score 3):

Since the restriction from using `toupper` strikes me as silly and counterproductive, I'd probably respond to such an assignment in a way that followed the letter of the prohibition while side-stepping its obvious intent, something like this:

```
#include <locale>
#include <iostream>

struct make_upper : private std::ctype < char > {
    void operator()(std::string &s){
        do_toupper(&s[0], &s[0]+s.size());
    }
};

int main() { 
    std::string input = "this is some input.";
    make_upper()(input);
    std::cout << input;
}
```

This, of course, produces the expected result:

```
THIS IS SOME INPUT.
```

Unlike the other answers I see posted here, this still gains all the normal advantages of using `toupper`, such as working on a machine that uses EBCDIC instead of ASCII encoding.

At the same time, I suppose I should admit that (for one example) when I was in fifth grade I was once told to do something like "write 'I will not talk in class', 50 times." so I turned in a paper containing one sentence that read "I will not talk in class 50 times." Sister Mary Ellen (yes, Catholic schools) was not particularly pleased.

Answer (score 1):

The [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) function with a [lambda expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) is one way to do it:

```
std::string s = "all uppercase";
std::transform(std::begin(s), std::end(s), std::begin(s),
    [](const char& ch)
    { return (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z' ? ch - 32 : ch) });
std::cout << s << '\n';
```

Should output

```
ALL UPPERCASE
```

But ***only*** if the system is using the ASCII character set (or the `ch - 32` expression will give unexpected results).

Comment: "not allowed to use toupper()" in the question

Comment: For those people without C++11, you should include `transform` with `toupper`.

Comment: `transform` with `toupper` can easily lead to undefined behaviour since `toupper` is spec'd to have UB if the argument is not representable as `unsigned char` (of which negative values are, and `char` may be signed)

Answer (score 0):

This is correct. But you should take care to add checks on the input. You could check if the characters are lowercase alphabets.

```
if (x[y] <= 'z') && (x[y] >= 'a')
    x[y] = x[y] - 32;
```

For readability, you should replace `32` by `'a' - 'A'`.

Also, your first function does nothing. It creates a copy of the string. Does the required actions on it. And then discards it because you are not returning it, and the function ends.

Comment: Maybe you should replace 123 and 96 as well?

Answer (score 0):

Sample Code:

- With correct checks of the range.
- With C++11 version (using range-for-loop).

Note: the production version should be using toupper. But the OP specifically state that can't used.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

const char upper_difference = 32;

void uppercaseCpp11(std::string& str) {
    for (auto& c : str) {
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
            c -= upper_difference;
    }
}

std::string UppercaseCpp11(std::string str) {
    uppercaseCpp11(str);
    return str;
}

void uppercase(std::string& x) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i) {
        if (x[i] >= 'a' && x[i] <= 'z')
            x[i] -= upper_difference;
    }
}

std::string Uppercase(std::string x) {
    uppercase(x);
    return x;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << Uppercase("stRing") << std::endl;
    std::string s1("StrinG");
    uppercase(s1);
    std::cout << s1 << std::endl;

    std::cout << UppercaseCpp11("stRing") << std::endl;
    std::string s2("StrinG");
    uppercaseCpp11(s2);
    std::cout << s2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    string x = "Hello World";
    char test[255];
    memset(test, 0, sizeof(test));
    memcpy(test, x.c_str(), x.capacity());
    for (int i = 0; i < x.capacity(); i++)
    {
        if (test[i] > 96 && test[i] < 123)
            test[i] = test[i] - 32;
    }

    x.assign(test);
```